# DataTable column value for Status field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have field in table `tbl_School` `[Status (bit, not null)]` whose value is `1/0`.
When this field is rendered in DataTable

```
 {
                      "data": "Status",
                      "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true
},
```

it shows value "true". But I want to display **"Active"** for **1** and **"Closed"** for **0** instead of **true/false**.
so I tried

```
{
                      "data": "Status",
                      "render" : function(data)
                      {
                          if (data === "true") { return "Active" }
                          else return "Closed"
                      },

                      "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true
},
```

but by implementing the above code, Status filed is showing `Closed` for `true` also. Also I tried ,

```
{
                      "data": "Status",
                      "render" : function(data)
                      {
                          if (data === "1") { return "Active" }
                          else return "Closed"
                      },

                      "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true
},
```

still getting `Closed` for `true` values. Why is it so ?

Comment: Because `===` compares both value and data type. Obviously "true" or "1" are both string data types. Which will always return false as `data` is a boolean.

Comment: you can use `if (data) { return "Active" }`

Comment: @AZ_ Thank you, it solved the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery DataTables render column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982049/jquery-datatables-render-column-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
      "data": "Status",
      "render" : function(data)
      {
          if (data) {
            return "Active" 
          }else{
            return "Closed"
          }
      },

      "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true
},
```