# LARAVEL - Unable to use destroy route when generating it with Route::resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

**CONTEXT**. I am working in Laravel 8 and I use the DataTables plugin to display the records from a database. As you will see in the code, I create all the routes to do CRUD using: Route::resource('animal', 'AnimalController'). This generates a path for the DESTROY method like this: animal/{id}

**PROBLEM**. When I press the delete button for a specific record, the record is deleted, fine, but the browser console returns this error: "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST", and therefore Javascript is broken and the alert that the record was deleted never show. And if I change the request type to POST instead of DELETE, the error tells me that POST is not supported and DELETE is!

**QUESTION**: what am I doing wrong?

*ROUTE*

```
Route::resource('animal', 'AnimalController');
```

*CONTROLLER to print the DataTable*

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $animals = DB::select('CALL sp_select_animal()');
        return DataTables::of($animals)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($animals){
                $actions  = '<a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>';
                $actions .= '<button type="button" id="'.$animals->id.'" data-name="'.$animals->name.'" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-1 delete">Delete</button>';
                return $actions;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
    return view('animal.index');
}
```

*CONTROLLER to delete record*

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $animal = DB::select('CALL sp_destroy_animal(?)', [$id]);
    return back();
}
```

*VIEW*

```
jQuery('#BTNdelete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = '{{ route("animal.destroy", ":xxx") }}';
    url = url.replace(':xxx', animalID);
    jQuery.ajax({
        "url": url,
        "type": 'DELETE',
        "data": {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery('#modal').modal('hide');
                toastr.warning('The record was successfully deleted', 'Delete Record', {timeOut:3000});
                jQuery('#tableAnimal').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});
```

Now everything works fine if I create a specific route to delete records, for example

```
Route::get('animal/delete/{id}', [AnimalController::class, 'destroy'])->name('animal.destroy')
```

and this would fix the problem. But I don't want to create an extra route. I want to use the routes generated by using the `resource()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problems in the JavaScript, but the root of your problem is that browsers can't make DELETE requests, so they have to [fake them](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing).

```js
// bind to the class of the button, not a non-existent ID
jQuery('button.delete').click(function(e) {
    // this isn't really needed, a button has no default action
    e.preventDefault();
    // you do want to stop the event from bubbling though
    e.stopPropagation();
    // this properly escapes the value for JavaScript, not HTML
    var url = @json(route("animal.destroy", ":xxx"));
    // WHAT IS animalID ???
    url = url.replace(':xxx', animalID);
    // build the post request with the fake method added
    jQuery.post(
        url,
        {_token: @json(csrf_token()), _method: "DELETE"},
        function(data) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery('#modal').modal('hide');
                toastr.warning('The record was successfully deleted', 'Delete Record', {timeOut:3000});
                jQuery('#tableAnimal').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }, 100);
        }
    );
});
```

But it must be said, your controller's `index()` method should NOT be dealing with HTML; that is exclusively the job of the view. Provide it only with the data it needs to build the HTML. This can be done [using `column.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982049/jquery-datatables-render-column-data) for an example.